# Recursive binary search with three arguments in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to get this recursive binary search right and got this far. So far I can get the first half to be shown correctly, but the right side of  mid is shown as if it where the left side. Where could I be wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int array[], int size, int searchValue)
{
    cout << "BST with size = " << size << "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << " ]" << endl;

    if (size >= 1)
    {
        int mid = (size - 1) / 2;
        cout << "Mid " << mid << endl;
        if (array[mid] == searchValue)
        {
            return mid;
        }
        if (array[mid] > searchValue)
        {
            return binarySearch(array,  mid, searchValue);
        }
        if (array[mid] < searchValue)
        {
            return binarySearch(array+mid+1, size-(mid + 1), searchValue);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {

    int val, myNums[1000];  // Yuck--magic number!
    int pos, cnt = -1;

    cout << "Enter numbers from smallest to largest, 0 to stop\n";
    do {
        cin >> myNums[++cnt];
    } while (myNums[cnt] != 0);

    do {
        cout << "Enter number to search for: ";
        cin >> val;
        if (val != 0) {
            pos = binarySearch(myNums, cnt, val);
            cout << "binarySearch reported " << pos << endl;
        }
    } while (val != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good start would be to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You could just pass the beginning and end indexes of each part of the array you want to search, instead of passing a smaller array to the binary search every time.

Comment: Your algorithm looks correct. The reporting seems odd because your partitioning is using smaller lengths, and pointer arithmetic to rebase the recursed calls (which is actually a good design, sans the reporting). Return a pointer to the slot where the element discovered resides rather than an index; null if the search was fruitless. The caller can do the pointer-difference to get the exact index, or you can be that caller, by wrapping this in an outer forwarding function, and do it for them.

Comment: I end up adding + (mid +1) at the end of the part that look to the right side and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not correct with a very error - you're trying to get the offset of a value in some fixed array, but you do manipulate that array here:

```
        return binarySearch(**array+mid+1**, size-(mid + 1), searchValue);
```

You can clearly see that this function doesn't work, because array+mid+1, in case of the 1st element after the mid, will return 0, while it's supposed to return:
    (int)(size/2)+1

I suggest you pass 'start' and 'end' range variables to the function.

Also this text:

```
cout << "BST with size = " << size << "[ ";
```

T in BST stands for 'Tree', but you do not create any tree.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this part:

```
if (array[mid] < searchValue)
{
    return binarySearch(array+mid+1, size-(mid + 1), searchValue);
}
```

You can use:

```
if (array[mid] < searchValue)
{
    int ans = binarySearch(array+mid+1, size-(mid + 1), searchValue);
    if (ans == -1)
        return -1;
    return mid + ans + 1;
}
```